Why isn't my VS code debugger working with programs that take command-line arguements?
I'm not sure why, but my programs that take command-line arguments aren't stopping at breakpoints. I researched and found out that the problem can be solved by configuring the launch.json file, but that isn't working for me either. I'll mention the code below, so please tell me if there's some error in it.
{"version": "0.2.0","configurations": [    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/caesar",
        "args": ["5"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

